# How to make a circuit to generate a signal to mute a signal and then gradually swell the gain back up?

Tags: compression, signal-processing

I assume this is a kind of sidechain insert for a hardware compressor circuit.

The application is for electric guitar.

The idea is to use a parallel signal chain; one straight signal channel, the other signal channel muting on pick attack, and then smoothly increasing it's gain to a higher level than the straight signal channel.

I plan to use a THAT 2080 series VCA in the effect channel, which has an exponential gain control law port ("linear-in-db").

Aim is to get something that sounds similar to acoustic feedback to the strings. Maybe 40-50 db gain fade in, then limiting the signal amplitude so it doesn't overload and clip.

Comment: Sounds like an envelope shaper to me.

Comment: Seems like this could be done with the right compressor and the right settings.  Not sure why you need anything more complex.

Comment: Widely known in the music synthesizer world as an envelope controller or envelope filter, with "ADSR" as a very common keyword.  ADSR is for Attack, Decay, Sustain, Release; for the volume-shaping events typically associated with a keyboard key press (A, D, and S), and release (R).  A web search for these terms may give you links to circuit diagrams for them.

Answer (score 0):

Is this electrical engineering? I would try sending an inverse of the signal you want to mute, alongside the target signal, then solder in a knob which modulate the phase of the signal away from 180º out of phase.

I might be oversimplifying my thought process on it, but I always think of phasing as a "short circuit." The waves cras and cancel each other out. Sending a current opposite but equal to the desired signal will accomplish this.